# Open single popup window from multiple onclicks of anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have one page in which multiple anchor links are present.

And i want to open a single pop-up window from onclick of all these anchors.

Please suggest any idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a class instead of an id. give all the links the same class:

```
$('.try').click(function(){
    //open popup code...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

1. Add a common CSS class name to all those 'anchor links'. Lets say 'single_popup_link' ( click me )
2. Use the following Jquery code snippet:

   $(document).ready(function(){

   ```
   $('a.single_popup_link').click(function() {
      //Include the code to call your popup window.    
   });
   ```

   });